# overriding button and after element

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using Wordpress and have the following code to style my menu items

css (the attributes I'm looking to change)

```
.main-nav li a {
  color: #222;
}

.main-nav li a:after {
  background-color: #d11e5d;
}
```

I have applied a custom class `.btn-contact` on one of the buttons so I can override its color and other attributes but I can't seem to target it. (using `.btn-contact { color: red; }` or .btn-contact `{ color: red !important; }` doesn't work )

the output

[image]

Comment: Please share a working example.

Comment: the working example is generated through wordpress so I don't have an independent working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
.btn-contact { 
   color: red !important; 
 }
```

The `!important` should override every other value for the same property.

Comment: I was under the impression that using important was very bad coding practice

Comment: Also it doesn't work since I think it doesn't target it specifically enough which is what I am having problems with

Comment: Yes, usage of `!important` is a bad practice, but not always. When you have to override 3rd party code & inline styles, you can or rather should use it. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the :after element is there for, but you need add the `content` property inside the rule, otherwise it will not render. You can also use en empty string like `content: ""`.

Comment: I apologize, there are other attributes in each css, those are just the ones I'm looking to alter in the .btn-content button

Comment: Oh all right sorry. Well, maybe there is another selector in the CSS that has higher priority then yours.

Comment: I assume the issue is that I'm not targeting the css specifically enough